# [Data Cloud][Marketing Cloud] - Business Unit Aware Activations Setup

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce-cdp, datacloud

What does the Checkbox "**Establish Contact on Business Unit mapping**" under Marketing Cloud Setup > Company Settings > Account Settings do?

[image]

Please find the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been asked this question many times and thought of providing the answer here for a wider audience. I hope you find this helpful:

When checking this box, you are allowing the new subscribers/Contacts to be **created** via Automation Studio activity along with BU Mapping ingestion. In contrast, If you do not check the box then any new contact that does not exist already in Marketing Cloud and flowing into the target BU through your BU Mapping will be rejected.

For more information related to "Enable Contacts to Business Unit Mapping" please visit the Data Cloud for Marketing BU Aware Guide. [Link here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/242/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/cdp_bu_aware_guide.pdf).

Best!

/Soubhi